# Get back all errors at once when using XSD/XML Validation

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I am adding an XSD validation to a tool I have created at work. This feature simply validates the XML created against a XSD mapping document. The code works properly as the current error is displayed in the console. The problem is that I would like to have some way for every error to appear in sequence. I do not know if this is possible but for now if someone could show me how to print ALL the errors in the console I would greatly appreciate it. Here is my code:

```
package xmlValidation;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class XMLValidation {


    public static JFileChooser uploadFile;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        XMLValidation.uploadFile();

        System.out.println("XML File Validates Against XSD"+validateXMLSchema("resources/camt.054.001.04.xsd",uploadFile.getSelectedFile().toString()));

    }

    public static boolean validateXMLSchema(String xsdPath, String xmlPath){

        try{

            SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(xsdPath));
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(xmlPath)));

        }catch(IOException | SAXException e){

            System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());

            return false;

        }   

        return true;

    }

    public static void uploadFile(){

        boolean uploadApproval = false;

        while(uploadApproval==false){//While upload approval has not been given..

            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();//Creates a new object of the JFileChooser class. 

            uploadFile = chooser;//Saves the upload file variable as the chooser response. 

            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("XML Files", "xml");
            //Sets the allowed file formats for upload. 

            chooser.setFileFilter(filter);//Activates the created file filter.

            chooser.setDialogTitle("Please choose a CamT54 file to upload");//Sets the title bar text. 

            //Completes once the user clicks ok. 
            int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);//
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                uploadApproval=true;
            }else{
                System.exit(0);
            }

            }
        }

}
```